# Disable Primefaces Idle Monitor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a web application in which the timeout feature has been disabled from the web.xml and we are now using prime faces idle monitor instead. This is obviously in a JSF application. The timeout is dynamic. Due to the nature of the application the timeout must be disabled in some cases. However when I set the timeout value to 0 or -1 the timeout occurs immediately. Any suggestions on how to disable the idle monitor?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `p:idleMonitor` has typically a `rendered` attribute, you could just set it to `false`. If this has to do be done on demand, you could set it via Ajax, e.g. with `RequestContext.update()` if you need to do it from a backing bean.
If the component isn't rendered anymore, it shouldn't trigger any events. I said *shouldn't* since I've not tested this and it's just a suggestion you've asked for.

**Edit**:
To set the session timeout, just put a session config element in your web.xml (under `web-app` of course), the number is the timeout in minutes.

```
<session-config>
    <!--session timeout every 20 minutes-->
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I have found that even when I attempt set render as false or use C:if test="timeout != 0" The timeout still occurs. I am attempting to replace it with something a little more standard. I am using the meta refresh goop to send the user back to the login page after timeout. However, it seems that setting the MaxInativeInterval in the session isn't doing anything as the user is never actually gets logged out. Is their a timeout feature built in to JSF?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't think you could dynamically modify the timeout value from the web.xml? Currently it's set to -1 in anticipation of resetting it via the session? Does it need to be set to a positive value before that will work?

Comment: I just noticed something very interesting, my session is timing out but not till after the defined time. It appears when running tomcat there is some variance between the actual set timeout value and when the session is killed.

Comment: This just keeps getting better apparently my issue isn't due to the variance but instead polling on the page. The idle monitor must by pass this...

Comment: Due to polling on the page I had to use the idle monitor. To handle the scenario in which its disabled, I had to put an if statement in the backing bean process used to logout the user.